# Visual Studio becomes unresponsive in "busy" state when adding specific items to ASP.NET MVC 4 projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

When attempting to add a new item of a specific type (i.e. `Add->New Controller`...) to an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, Visual Studio becomes unresponsive with the phrase "`Preview is not available for this item type`" in the status bar.  At this point the application is officially "Running" according to Windows, consuming negligible CPU cycles, and not using any additional memory.  Although, "Running," neither the application nor its window respond to user input, but the Task Manager can close it via the End Task button on the Application tab. 
Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: are you sign in with VS or TFS ?

Comment: work in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

Some workarounds suggested by various Developers are as follows:

1. You can also create a new solution in VS2012, then import all of the
   existing code files from the original solution. Add => Controller...
   will then start functioning properly again.
2. Select Add => New Item from the context menu, then choose MVC 4
   Controller. However, you don't get any of the scaffolding that you
   do with the wizard.
3. Run devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276(v=vs.100).aspx
4. Disable "**Visual Studio Hosting Process**" in each executable project's
   properties (build tab, all the way at the bottom)
5. Disable **`Intellitrace`** on Debug in Tools, Options, **`Intellitrace`**